# Custom Metadatafield in Document and Web content in Liferay

Tags: hook, metadata, liferay

I want a metadata field getting values from database record. This metadata field should be added to document.

Can anyone provide a solution to my requirement.??

Comment: You mean to say, you want to create a metadata-field which gets value from ***your* custom database table**?

Comment: yes i mean it or any other solution to achieve it....

Comment: Custom document types in document library could provide this functionallity. Here is a useful tutorial about it: http://liferaytutorialpoint.blogspot.com.br/2013/12/document-metadata-sets-types.html

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are using Liferay 6.1.

### Web Content Structures

As for Web Content, you could programmatically create a `JournalStructure` (see `JournalStuctureLocalServiceUtil`) and populate the list of possible values for your structure field with values coming out of the database. You can put this "import code" inside a batch job, so your structure field and the values inside the external database are always in sync.

### Document Metadata

How to do this with **Metadata Sets** is probably more interesting, as not only Dynamic Data Lists and Documents & Media use this in Liferay 6.1; as of 6.2, Web Content structures will utilize the same metadata API in favor of the old Journal API.

For this to implement, check out the `xsd` column of the `DDMStructure` table. It has more or less the same format as the XML for a `JournalStructure`, however there are more options available. Use `DDMStructureLocalServiceUtil#addStructure` to add such a new structure. Again, run this inside a batch so you always have the latest external DB values.